# Get resized images from Google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

When initially loading my website, I need to load a couple of images from my Google cloud storage that have been uploaded by users. To speed up my load time, I would like to get the images in lower resolution.

Is there a way to specify this with the URL, like an additional URL parameter?...

I'm using signed URLs that look like this:

```
baseURL + "?GoogleAccessId=" + GoogleAccessStorageId + "&Expires=" + Expiration + "&Signature=" + UrlEncodedSignature
```

as specified here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#Signed-URLs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not directly, no. AppEngine has an [Images API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/) that can serve images from GCS, and that image serving can include transformations, but GCS itself is agnostic to the type of objects it is storing and has no special knowledge of image files or transforming them.

One option would be storing a smaller version of each image at the time that you upload the original. Then you may simply refer to that object directly. A second option would be to serve the images through AppEngine in order to take advantage of its Images API.

Comment: I also thought about storing multiple versions, but wanted to avoid that if possible... The Images API looks great, but - as I'm not familiar with Python - is there any chance this can be done in Node.js (anytime soon)?