# Best approach to use a CDN service

Tags: google-app-engine, post, cdn, image-scaling

I am a mobile developer trying to do backend development. It is going more or less well but still having doubts about some subjects. Currently I want to add a Google app engine service to upload and resizing images on Google Storage. Now I am trying to define the best way to upload it because image is just a part of the object form data.

Option 1: I know I can use Javascript to send two different forms (one for the data to my own controller and the other one for image to the app engine service) pointing to different processing URIs and create a random string to use as a link between image and data (because after uploading successfully on Google Storage I need to write the URL on my object data.

Option 2: Upload everything in one form just with my service and store temporally the image locally and send it on background calling app engine from my controller.

Option 3: Storing everything like now and use a background task to send image to app engine and the replacing the image by the returned URI.

No one of this options convinces me, please if some of you faced this before, enlighten me.
Regards,

Comment: Can you confirm if in the option 3 you are talking about something like described here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48117282/resize-google-cloud-images-via-request-url ? It seems like there it worked.

Comment: Interesting article Samuel, now I can't answer you, but then I'll check it out. Let me come back later.